# Error en hilos python

Tags: python, tkinter, hilos

Estoy haciendo un codigo de Hilos en una ventana de Tkinter, donde debe hacer un contador, las funciones estan bien, pero en el hilo me aparece este error:

> RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

Alguien sabe porque?

```
t= threading.Thread(target=Vowels, args=())
t.start()
t2=threading.Thread(target=Emojis, args=())
t2.start()
t3=threading.Thread(target=Simbol, args=())
t3.start()
```

Comment: Podrias poner un poco mas de codigo? o un contexto?

args no es necesario que lo ingreses si no llevas argumentos en tu funcion.